# What method would you suggest for finding the zeros of this particular polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I'd like to be able to find the zeros of something like this:

> $$0= k + \left[\binom{n}{2}-\binom{n}{1}\right]x+\left[\binom{n}{3}-\binom{n}{2}\right]x^{2}+\cdots+\left[\binom{n}{n}-\binom{n}{n-1}\right]x^n$$

Where $k$ and $n$ are general constants. What approach would you use?

Edit:  I'm primarily interested in finding roots that are bound between 0 and 1, non-inclusive.

Comment: What do you know about the polynomial? Are you looking for *all* the roots? Real roots? The largest root in absolute value?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in real roots that are bounded between 0 and 1.

Comment: Is n also a general constant?

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$$(1+x)^n = 1+ \binom n1 x +\binom n2 x^2+...+\binom nn x^n $$

Comment: This implies a root of $x=-1$ with a multiplicity of $n$.  Are you suggesting that the polynomial I've posed has no real roots between 0 and 1?

Comment: I just gave you a hint. You are finishing the problem, using the hint carefully.